# Cannot remove openjdk without having an older version installed, how can I do so?

Tags: apt, java, uninstall, openjdk, oracle

I am running Ubuntu 14.04.1 64-bit with Oracle Java installed, hence I would like to uninstall `openjdk`, but when I try to uninstall it via the command line I get the following output:

```
~$ sudo apt-get remove openjdk-7-jre openjdk-7-jre-headless 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  launchpad-getkeys linux-image-3.13.0-43-generic
  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-43-generic python-appindicator python-keyring
  python-launchpadlib python-lazr.restfulclient python-lazr.uri python-oauth
  python-secretstorage python-wadllib xclip yad
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  icedtea-6-jre-cacao icedtea-6-jre-jamvm icedtea-netx openjdk-6-jre
  openjdk-6-jre-headless openjdk-6-jre-lib ttf-dejavu-extra
Suggested packages:
  icedtea-plugin sun-java6-fonts fonts-ipafont-gothic fonts-ipafont-mincho
  ttf-telugu-fonts ttf-oriya-fonts ttf-kannada-fonts ttf-bengali-fonts
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  default-jre default-jre-headless octave openjdk-7-jre openjdk-7-jre-headless
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  icedtea-6-jre-cacao icedtea-6-jre-jamvm icedtea-netx openjdk-6-jre
  openjdk-6-jre-headless openjdk-6-jre-lib ttf-dejavu-extra
0 upgraded, 7 newly installed, 5 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 37.8 MB of archives.
After this operation, 3,122 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

which hints that another version(former) of `openjdk` will be installed after removing `openjdk-7-jre` and `openjdk-7-jre-headless`. I already have Oracle Java installed so I want to uninstall `openjdk` without messing the package manager, how can I do so?

Comment: Install `aptitude` via `sudo apt-get install aptitude`, [Edit] your question and add the output of `aptitude why openjdk-7-jre` and `aptitude why openjdk-7-jre-headless`